# Serializing MVC form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to serialize an MVC form with jQuery the same way the MVC engine does? Precisely, by being smart enough to "assemble" the inputs data into the Model objects?

For example, let's say this is my simple Model:

```
public List<Person> People {get;set;}
```

And this is my form:

```
<form>
    <input name="People[0].Id" value="9B776FB9-28B9-4364-A320-22E00A3E05D4" type="hidden">
    <input name="People[0].Name" value="Jon Doe" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Desired result:

```
People: [
    {
        Id: "9B776FB9-28B9-4364-A320-22E00A3E05D4",
        Name: "Jon Doe"
    }
]
```

I tried with $("form").serialize(), but this is the returned Json:

```
[
    {
        name: "People[0].Id",
        value: "9B776FB9-28B9-4364-A320-22E00A3E05D4"
    },
    {
        name: "People[0].Name",
        value: "Jon Doe"
    }
]
```

As you can see, what it does is just returning each input as a separate object rather than "Understanding" that the 2 inputs represent each a property of the same object.

Any way I can achieve this?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abu6mh1z/

Comment: `$("form").serialize()` does not return that - it return `{ People[0].Id: '9B776FB9-28B9-4364-A320-22E00A3E05D4', People[0].Name: 'Jon Doe' }`. Why don't you want to use `.serialize()` which is correct and will bind to your model (`List<Person> model`) when you post it (and your fiddle is using `.serializeArray()`, not `.serialize()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It does. Check his JsFiddler console result.

Comment: @Oluwafemi, Read the last sentence of my last comment :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's true, I used serializeArray() in the jsFiddle, because serialize() doesn't return Json. How do I return Json from serialize() so I can test what you're saying?

Comment: Why do you want json? You can always use `JSON.stringify($("form").serialize())`, but I assume this is an ajax call so its not necessary at all - just use `data: $('form').serialize(),` and do **not** include the `contentType` option

Comment: I need json because the reason why I'm doing this is to have the ability to process the form data on the client side. I don't want to actually submit the form, at this stage.

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abu6mh1z/1/ but `JSON.stringify($("form").serialize())` doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggested that assuming your using ajax to post the data. If you want the format you have shown, then you will need to manually generate it :)

Answer (score -1):

I Already use Serialize form object in my project .

You have to write below code for  serialize form object .

```
var formId = '#form2';

var SData = $(formId).serialize();
```

You have to define form in View Index .

```
<form id="form2">
```

If you are using Post method, then you need to define [HttpPost] in Action.

---

A model which you are using in Index, same model you need to use as parameter in Action. Please check above criteria, you will definitely able to serialize form object, if you failed, tell me we will resolve your problem.

Thanks .